# Probability distributing $n$ gifts at a party

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to solve the following question

There are $n$ people at a Christmas party, each carrying a gift. All the
presents are put in a bag and mixed, then each person randomly takes one.
What is the probability that no one gets their own present?

Whe can take $A_i$ equal the $ith$ present that gets his or her own gift. So I can certainly calculate the following

$$P\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i$$

Considering that $P(A_i) = \frac 1 n$, i found that $P(A_{i} \cup A_{j})=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ (I found this equality in another post, but I don't understand it very well, could someone guide me a little?)

From where i note that

$$P\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_i=\frac{1}{n!}$$

it seems that I can take this to the taylor polynomial expansion, but I think that to do this is to think about the probability that at least one receives the gift, is it the same thing?.

Thanks!

Comment: Go from one person to the other person. The probability the person i=1 gets his/her own present is $\frac1n$. Then $n-1$ presents are left. The next person have to choose his/her own specific present. The probability is $\frac1{n-1}$. Thus the probability that both take their own presents is $\frac1n\cdot \frac1{n-1}=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword for this scenario is **derangements**. You can find the first few on the Online Encyclopedia for Integer Sequences at [**A000166**](https://oeis.org/A000166).

The **number of derangements** on $n$ objects, sometimes denoted $!n$, is the number of permutations without fixed points.

So, your question for $n$ people can be rephrased as computing $!n/n!$.

As an example, let's compute the probability that no one gets their own gift with $10$ people:

The number of derangements, as linked above, is $1334961$.

The number of arrangements, meaning $10!$, is $3628800$.

Therefore, the probability that no one gets their own gift is:

$$\frac{1334961}{3628800} = \frac{16481}{44800} = 0.3678794642857\text{ } 1428571 \text{ } 1428571 \ldots \approx 0.37$$

The $0.37$ may indeed clue you in to a well-known fact (stated here without proof):

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{!n}{n!} = \frac{1}{e}$$